# How to provide a response example with this structure in OpenAPI 3?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi

Is it possible to provide a response example that is an object with an array attribute and a string attribute?

I have the following OpenAPI 3 definition:

```json
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {


                "examples": {
                  "results": [
                    {
                        "abc": 20
                    }
                  ],
                  "totalCount": 69
                },

                "schema": {
                  "results":"array",
                  "totalCount": "integer"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

But Swagger UI shows an error when I put `"totalCount": 69` inside the `examples` object.

[image: error image]

Comment: Just to clarify - do you use OpenAPI 3.x (`"openapi": "3.x.x"`) or OpenAPI 2.0 (`"swagger": "2.0"`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `examples` (plural) to `example` (singular), and also provide a proper `schema` for the response.

```json
  "responses": {
    "200": {
      "description": "OK",
      "content": {
        "application/json": {
          "example": {
            "results": [
              {
                "abc": 20
              }
            ],
            "totalCount": 69
          },

          "schema": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "results": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "abc": {
                      "type": "integer"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "totalCount": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks! and it seems that OpenAPI 2.0 wants "examples" (plural). it'll work as "example" (singular) but it'll give an error `should not have additional properties additionalProperty: example`

Comment: @RyanLoggerythm OP used OpenAPI 3.0. For 2.0 example(s) syntax, see https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/adding-examples/